# MKAnnotation protocol inheritance

Tags: swift, mkmapview, protocols, mkannotation

I need to create a protocol that inherits from MKAnnotation:

```
protocol Annotable: MKAnnotation {
    ...
}

class Annotation: NSObject, Annotable {
    var title: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

    init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```

There is no problem when I add a couple of those annotations to the mapView.

```
mapView.addAnnotations([Annotation(...), Annotation(...), ...]
```

But when I try to loop on the annotations collection, the app crashes at runtime:

```
for annotation in mapView.annotations { // fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
    print(annotation.title)
}
```

My question is simple: **why?**

Since Annotation conforms to MKAnnotation, it is no surprise that they can be added to the mapView. So why could not we retrieve them?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wondering if this stops the crash ?  let pins = [Annotation(...), Annotation(...), Annotation(...), ... ].map({ $0 as MKAnnotation })    mapView.addAnnotations(pins)

Comment: Does this help - I had similar issue with mapkit and protocols a while ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237753/conform-to-protocol-mkannotation-via-custom-protocol

Comment: @DogCoffee map to MKAnnotation does not help.

Comment: @DogCoffee thanks for the link but my problem is different. Yours is about adding an array of inherited protocols, which is not supported in swift 2.2. I did not have this problem since I am adding concrete types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this by declaring your protocol as an `@objc` protocol:

```
@objc protocol Annotable: MKAnnotation {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Excellent question. I don't know. It seems curious to me that `class Annotation: NSObject, Annotable { ... }`, where `Annotable` conforms to `MKAnnotation`, doesn't work, but `class Annotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation { ... }` does.